# Is it possible for Google Apps Script to send emails based on specific Google-form input?

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-forms

I am new to app script and I am trying to make a script using Google Apps Script that will automatically send an email to specific people based on the input given from a Google Form. I would like the script to only email a person if the answer submitted pertains to them.

For instance, say someone would like to volunteer at a soup kitchen in one area and they choose that area out of 5 possible areas. I would like the script to only email the soup kitchen of choice, upon submission of the form. The answer's may vary amongst the 5 options depending on a new person submitting is and it is possible to check multiple options.

Right now my script sends an email to everyone with the choice chosen but I only need it to email the person in charge of that specific choice. Is this possible? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You can definitely read what has been submitted and then send an email based on the script.  Perhaps you have another sheet/tab in the file which lists the Position, Recipient Name and email.  You can then use the script to look up the recipient and send the email to them.

Comment: It is possible.  There is an Add-on that will do what you want.  No programming needed.  [Link - Google Chrome Store - Forms Add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/data-director-for-forms/bjlicikmbfbjckkgemmiddonmigijpbj?authuser=0)

Comment: @Karl_S Yes, I am using a sheet with the forms responses to run the script. I will try using another sheet with the response I want to send for each different location. Do you think I should make a separate sheet for each location or can I do this all on the same sheet?

Comment: @SandyGood thanks so much for the tip! Hopefully that will be all I need and I won't need to program myself.

Comment: @SandyGood I think your Add-on suggestion is going to work for me. Thanks so much for the help! This is an awesome little tool!!

Comment: If you use custom code, the all sheets (tabs) can be in the same file, @KarmaPimp .  SandyGood has provided you with a good add-on solution which is newer than the last time I looked.  If you end up going the route of custom code, create new posts to ask specific questions.

Comment: @Karl_S Thanks for the help! I think I am going to write my own script as the add on only allows for up to 4 emails of which I would need much more emails than that depending on a variety of input combinations of the Form. Do you know if it is possible to create an array like structure as in C and use a pointer and a counter of some sort (maybe if statements or for loop) to point to the inputs that are submitted by the user on the form and then send emails out based on those inputs?

Comment: @KarmaPimp See the [Simple Mail Merge Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge) for source code to loop through entries and send an email.  Google Apps Scipt is JavaScript based. It sounds as if you have enough experience with other languages to adopt the tutorial.  Ask specific questions in new threads when you have any, and include pertinent code with the question.